# Estimate sum of certain arithmetic functions

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $\mu, \phi, I$ denote mobius function, Euler-phi function and identity function, respectively.

Let $$f(n) := \frac{\mu^2(n)}{I(n)\phi(n)}$$

I follow some guide steps to estimate $\sum_{i=1}^\infty f(n)$ and $\sum_{n \leq x}\frac{1}{\phi(n)}$.

1) I show that ($*$ := Dirichlet convolution) $$\frac{1}{\phi} = \frac{1}{I}* f.$$

Since $I, \phi, \mu$ are multiplicative, $\frac{1}{\phi}, \frac{1}{I}*f$ are multiplicative. So it is enough to verify its value at prime power. A calculation show that $$\frac{1}{\phi}(p^a) = \frac{1}{I}*f (p^a)$$ for $p$ prime. So I am fine with this step.

2) I want to show that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty f(n) = O(1)$, or it the serie converges.

Sol. (Update : my new approach) $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu^2(n)}{n\phi(n)} = \sum_{n=p_1p_2...p_k, \ p_i \neq p_j} \frac{1}{n(p_1 - 1)...(p_k - 1)}\\ = \sum_{n = 2p_1p_2...p_k, \\ p_i \neq p_j, p_m \neq 2} \frac{1}{n(p_1 - 1)...(p_k - 1)} + \sum_{n = p_1...p_k, \\ p_i \neq p_j, p_m \neq 2}\frac{1}{n(p_1 - 1)(p_2 - 1)...(p_k - 1)}.$$

For any prime $p > 2$, $$p^{1/2} < p-1 \ \ \ \ -----(1).$$ Then $$\sum_{n = p_1...p_k, \\ p_i \neq p_j, p_m \neq 2}\frac{1}{n(p_1 - 1)(p_2 - 1)...(p_k - 1)} \leq \sum_{n = p_1...p_k, \\ p_i \neq p_j, p_m \neq 2} \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$$ so it is convergent. For the first sum $$\sum_{n = 2p_1p_2...p_k, \\ p_i \neq p_j, p_m \neq 2} \frac{1}{n(p_1 - 1)...(p_k - 1)}$$ I think it should be similar, but the argument is not exactly the same
since $(1)$ does not hold.

Anyone has a better idea about this ?

3) From 2), for $n \geq 2$ $$\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{1}{\phi(n)} = O(\log x).$$ I think I will use 1) and use Dirichlet hyperbola method to do the estimation. But it does not go as I expected. Not much Idea what should I do.

Hint, suggestion, or help please ?

Comment: These are not just "certain" functions, but very famous ones in analytic number theory.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Really ? I dont know that it is famous. I just start studying Analytic number theory. Dont know much about it. Should I change the problem topic ?

Comment: I don't get what you are doing, you are using $\ast$ for the multiplication ?? And since $f(n)$ is multiplicative and is $\mathcal{O}(n^{-2})$ :  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n) = \prod_p (1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty f(p^k)) = \prod_p (1+\frac{1}{p\phi(p)}) =\prod_p (1+\frac{1}{p (p-1)})$ that is not very different to $\prod_p (1+\frac{1}{p^2}) = \frac{\zeta(4)}{\zeta(2)}$.

Comment: And $\sum_{n \le N} f(n) = F(0) + \mathcal{O}(1/n)$ where $F(0)= \sum_{n =1}^\infty f(n)$

Comment: @user1952009 Surely $*$ is being used for Dirichlet convolution?  But it looks like $\times$ is being used for pointwise multiplication.

Comment: @ErickWong If he meant $\ast$ is as usual the Dirichlet convolution, then I don't think what he wrote is correct

Comment: @user1952009 Yeah I don't quite follow the logic that leads to $I/\phi = 1 * \mu^2/\phi$, but the line before that makes a lot of sense with $*$ as convolution and $\times$ as multiplication.

Comment: @ErickWong ok I made a mistake sooner :) anyway with $H(s) = \sum_n \frac{1}{\phi(n)}n^{-s} = \prod_p (1+\sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{p^{-sk}}{p^{k-1}(p-1)})$ I think finding the $C$  in $H(s) \sim \frac{C}{s}$ as $s \to 0$ is as hard as $\prod_p (1+\frac{1}{p (p-1)})$. But maybe I'm wrong. What is $\frac{1}{H(s)}$ ?

Comment: For $\prod_p ( 1 + \frac{1}{p(p-1) } ) $ I think this simplifies to $\frac{\zeta(2)\zeta(3)}{\zeta(6)}$.

Comment: Yes, * is for Dirichlet convolution, $\times$ is simple real number multiplication.

Comment: Can you please explain what you are doing ? Is it for No.2 ? I dont quite understand.

Comment: @ErickWong well done $\frac{\zeta(2)\zeta(3)}{\zeta(6)} = \prod_p \frac{1-p^{-6}}{(1-p^{-2})(1-p^{-3})} =\prod_p \frac{1+p^{-3}}{1-p^{-2}} =\prod_p 1+\frac{p^{-3}+p^{-2}}{1-p^{-2}}=\prod_p 1+\frac{p^{-1}+1}{p^2-1} = \prod_p 1+\frac{\frac{p+1}{p}}{(p+1)(p-1)} = \prod_p 1+\frac{1}{p(p-1)}$

Comment: @user117375 as I wrote $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)= \prod_p 1+\frac{\mu(p)^2}{p\phi(p)}=  \prod_p 1+\frac{1}{p(p-1)}$ and ErickWong found it is $= \frac{\zeta(2)\zeta(3)}{\zeta(6)}$

Comment: @user1952009 k, I am not sure how summation turn to multiplication, and I want to keep it as simple as possible. I have my new argument update above, and I think it sounds okay. I will appreciate if you can take a look.

Comment: @user1952009 Also, the biggest problem is part 3. I believe I should use the fact from 1) that $1/\phi = 1/I * f$, and try to estimate. When I have function as a convolution of two functions, I think of Dirichlet hyperbola method, But I cannot do it, can you help me with that ?

Comment: I am not a professional, thus I don't know if could be useful some of the techniques (that I try understand) explained in this short and nice paper, on **arXiV**. Next reference is dedicated to calculate a bound for a sum involving a different counting function (yours is Euler's totient function). Also related with other of your questions: in this paper were calculated identities for the logarithmic integral. The author is a great mathematician: **Ivic,** *On a sum involving the prime counting function* $\pi(x)$. No the same calculations that you need, but it will be interesting for you.